# How to deploy Google assistant sample code on Heroku

Tags: heroku, actions-on-google, google-home

I'm trying to deploy the sample apiai-facts-about-google-nodejs on heroku.  I've followed the instructions but when trying to start the app, in the logs, I get the error:

```
functions deploy factsAboutGoogle --trigger-http
sh: 1: functions: not found
```

This seems to be because the code was written for Google Cloud Functions.  I think the command:

```
functions deploy xxxxxx --trigger-http
```

is GCF specific.  Do I need to modify this code in some way to make it run on Heroku?

I saw [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773484/how-do-i-deploy-a-actions-on-google-on-heroku) which seems to indicate it should just work as-is, but that's not what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1):

A previous version of the sample which worked on app engine was compatible with Heroku. The latest version is designed for Cloud functions and you will have modify the code (you could find the previous version in the Git history).

Answer (score 1):

As @leon-nicholls noted:

> A previous version of the sample which worked on app engine was compatible with Heroku. The latest version is designed for Cloud functions and you will have modify the code

Here is a working with heroku version of the "Facts about Google" sample exemple:
https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-facts-about-google-nodejs/tree/d1ac5ac5b3838569f1e55602e0103d8863971572